# Is it possible to re-DataBind a DropDownList upon postback triggered by SelectedIndexChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, concurrency

Let's say I have a DropDownList of product categories and a ListView of products based on the category selection in the DropDownList. When a user visits the page, there is a possibility of conconrency issue as new product belonging to a new category may be added to the inventory as the user is browsing.

When the user selects a different category to view(a SelectedIndexChanged event) and causes a postback, I want the DropDownList to update the list of categories to include the new category being concurrently added and at the same time still able to make a change of selected index. The DropDownList does not seem to support this updating while postback. So how do I handle this concurrent issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to **bind and rebind regardless of checking postback dropdown in Page_Init** event. It **will not cause any change in selected index of the dropdown** and you can continue your work properly, the page init method called before loading view state. means your dropdown index will be selected after this method and you can access it in dropdown_selectedIndexChanged method.

For more information on [ASP.Net page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

**Edit 1:** have a look on sample code

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here you bind your dropdown
    // don't check IsPostBack
    DropdownList1.DataSource = db.GetCategories();
    DropdownList1.DataTextField = "TextField";
    DropdownList1.DataValueField = "ValueField";
    DropdownList1.DataBind();
}
```

ASP.Net loads controls viewstate after **Page_Init** and before **Page_Load** event, so DropDownList1's selectedIndex will not be affected, and you got desired results.

Comment: Bravo! Your understanding of the Page Lifecycle is most astounding! Now what happens if the user choose the last item but meanwhile some items have been deleted, so the new item list is shorter? An exception?

Comment: hmm, in that case Page_Init events binds dropdown, but when asp.net try to set the selected value and if the value whether it is at last index or in between, it would not be found in dropdown, and SelectedIndex will become -1

Answer (score 1):

just check if the page-call is a postback with `IsPostBack` and then call `dataBind()` on your dropdownlist

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add the problem is, after re-DataBind, the SelectedIndex is automatically reset to 0. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: the user wants to rebind the dropdown after postback, and he also wants no change in selectedIndex of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can very well change the data source after the post-back. You can even refresh the data in it by calling DataBind() method on the DropDownListbox.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add the problem is, after re-DataBind, the SelectedIndex is automatically reset to 0. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: well since we are rebinding the datasource it will surely be reset. But to workaround this you can save the selected index item in a variable and after rebinding, find the index of item in dropdownlistbox  and set it as the Selected Item.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this if you can't bind in `Page_Init` for some reason (as in my situation):

```
var selected = ddList.SelectedValue;
ddList.DataSource = DBHelper.GetCategories();
ddList.DataBind();
ddList.SelectedValue = selected;
```

You'll still need to handle situation when selected category was deleted.